# Hide Dota 2 Losses From Profile?

Tags: dota-2

I understand losses are hidden from other people viewing my profile, but is it possible to hide the losses for myself? I can't seem to find an option to toggle it in the settings, but perhaps there's something I can edit or comment out in the config files?

I know I'm terrible, I just don't want to be reminded that I am every time I visit my profile page.

Cheers.

Comment: did you see my profile and thought that I am hiding my losses? I simply never lost a game - Chuck Norris

Comment: You could make your profile private so others cannot see it, but to hide it from yourself - you would have to change the UI.

Answer (score 3):

You could just win more games than you lose?

But in all seriousness, no there's not a way to hide that from yourself. At least not through "standard" means. Might be some config file out there you can edit and hide it.

One way to win more games and actually get better at the game is to play with friends. Having 2, 3, or even 4 other people to play with helps a ton. It allows you to really communicate and pick heroes which synergize well.

Also, try to not play all pick. That's just asking to get terrible team compositions. Play single draft, random draft, or one of the captain modes.

Comment: If you play either of the Captain modes without taking captain yourself or being in a 5-stack, (or worse, sometimes even in a 5-stack), you WILL end up with randomed heroes, a bad team composition, heroes you can't play, or some such, once in a while.  In my experience most captains are pretty good about not letting that happen, but it does happen.

Comment: You should be able to avoid this im CM and CD by just communicating during the draft. Yes, there sometimes is that guy that spams the "become captain" button and then picks 5 carries or w/e, but the usual drafter listens to input and is more compelled to explain his drafting thoughts when the players communicate.

Comment: I generally have very good experiences in CM/D. Granted, I almost always play with at least two other people, but I do play alone sometimes and even then I get decent people for the most part. I always try to be captain if I'm alone, as it gives me the confidence that a decent comp is being picked. And if it ends up sub par, well then it's my fault and I can't be mad.

Answer (score 0):

NO, there is no option that hides your losses from yourself. But it shouldn't matter because the only way to get better is by losing and learning from your mistakes.